# Linked Server directly to database

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

Say I have a query like this:

```
select * from openquery ([linkedservername],'select * from [databasename].dbo.person')
```

Is there a way of omitting [databasename].dbo.? I have an enormous query I want to put inside OPENQUERY and appending [databasename].dbo.
to every table name will be a pain.

Comment: Only to remove `databasename.dbo.` --> NO, but you can use [synonym](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187552.aspx) to remove reference. Also, refer to http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-synonym/

Comment: are all tables in the same database? if so, you could just make that database the default for the login being used

Comment: @Bob Klimes, how would I do that.  Is there a command I can run for the session only? i.e. external sessions would not have this default.

Comment: you would need to run alter login(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828.aspx) on the remote server. Unfortunately you would not be able to make this change for your session only. if your local login is used exclusively for this query, you could create remote login with desired db and map the two logins in linked server definition.